# Bypass SSL public key pinning to do MITM with the public key

Tags: ssl, https, mitmproxy

I'm looking to test a MITM attack on a project of mine, and I have the public key that is pinned. I'm trying to use fiddler to do this, so I guess I would have to change the public key of the trusted cert that fiddler generates to decrypt HTTPS traffic, but I'm not that much into it. Is it even possible to do a MITM attack, even if I have the public pinned key?

Comment: The public key is not sufficient for a MITM attack. As it name implies, it should be considered public anyway so if knowledge of the public key would be sufficient for MITM than we would be all screwed. What you would need instead is the server certificate (which contains the public key) and its matching __private__ key.

Comment: Ah okay, that makes sense.
Thanks for clarifying.

If I want to modify requests sent from from the server to the application, wouldn't I then just need only the public key, sinse thats is whats checked from the application? I don't need to send data to the server.

Comment: During the TLS handshake the server proofs to the client that it has access to the private key by signing some "challenge". The client then can check the signature with the public key in the certificate. Only when this check is successful the client will continue with further checks on the provided certificate - in your case to check if the private key matches. Therefore, the public key alone is not sufficient, one also need the matching private key.